# Should I stored current unit in database or just use .NET RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol

Tags: .net, localization, currency

[image]

I saw this in a project I am working on, they stored country name and currency type like this.

Would it be better if the currency things use the System.Globalization that .Net provided instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.isocurrencysymbol.aspx

Is there any good reason that we should stored those currency in our own database ?

Comment: How would you go from `CountryId` to `CurrencySymbol`?

Comment: we can changed that structure, using something like ThreeLetterISORegionName instead.

Comment: Is your application the only one using this database? If not, are any of the other application not written using .NET?

Comment: I see, so there is an ios application that might connect to this system too. so it is more solid to store this in database right ?

Comment: If they need to share data - the iOS version is not likely to have `RegionInfo`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definite right or wrong way to store your currency symbols, it very much depends on your requirements and your expected future requirements. If you want to store the currency symbol rather than the ISO Code and that works for you then fine.  However, it might give you difficulties in the future when your requirements extend to, for example, retrieve the currency's exchange rate against the US $.  To do this you would probably use a third-party web-service to get the exchange rate and this web service would most likely require you to specify the currency as an ISO Code.  If you only stored your currency symbol then you would have to write a method to convert the symbol into the ISO Code.

However, in your database table you are storing the currency against the country.  Would it not be easier if you simply stored the country's ISO code in this table instead.  Then you can use the RegionInfo class to get the currency symbol for that county, as well as lots of other information about the country, which may be useful in the future.

So, my recommendation is that you store the country's ISO code instead of currency.